# Retaining filter options when switching languages

Tags: r, shiny, translation, shiny-reactivity, lookup-tables

I am creating an R Shiny app that allows the user to filter data by 5 different parameters, each parameter having 12+ options. This app exists in both French and English. It works for the most part, except when the user has options selected and then tries to toggle the languages (either English to French or French to English). The app will either crash or will reset all the filters the user selected. I would like for my app to retain the user's selections when switching languages. The app translates these options perfectly fine overall, but as I mentioned, the issue is with retention. You can access the app [here](https://jbissessar.shinyapps.io/JBcensusportal/) to see the problem.

I have put together a .csv file called "translation" that contains translations of all the filter options for all the parameters. It's split up into two columns: "en" for English, "fr" for French. Basically, I would like for the app to refer to a look-up table of these translations and simply match everything up when the user has made selections and then switches languages.

Basically, I'm not sure if I need to change the `selectInput` or if it's just a matter of adding a few lines that allows the app to reference a look-up table to retain values.

Here is the code for the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------
load("app2.RData") 

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(   
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 8,
             h2("Census Discovery Portal"),
             h2("Portail de découverte du recensement")
      ),
      column(width = 4,
             # Experimented with a shinyWidgets switch input (English = TRUE; French = FALSE):
             switchInput(inputId = "language",
                         onLabel = "English",
                         offLabel = "Français",
                         onStatus = "danger", # red
                         offStatus = "primary", # blue
                         value = TRUE, # English is default
                         size = "default") 
      ),
      bookmarkButton() #creates bookmark button underneath language switch
    ),
    # puts selectors into two columns
    fluidRow( 
      style = "background-color: #33c435",
      column(width = 6,
             selectInput("subject", "Subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(x = dat$subject, split = ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
             selectInput("census_year", "Census Year(s) covered by item", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
      ),
      column(width = 6,
             selectInput("geo_units", "Geographic units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
             selectInput("geo_coverage", "Geographic coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
             selectInput("format", "Format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$format, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
      )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      width = 12, # default width of a DT is 8; sets to full browser window width
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Search Results", DT::DTOutput('ex1')),
        tabPanel("Details", DT::DTOutput("details"))
      )
    )
    
  )
  
}

# SERVER ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  # handles occasional crash on exit
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
  
  # selection filtering
  
  observe({
    if (input$language == TRUE) {
      filtered_dat <- subset(dat, language == "EN")[,-21] # Remove identifier column
      
      
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", "Subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year","Census Year(s) covered by item", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units","Geographic units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage","Geographic coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format","Format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
      
    } else {
      filtered_dat <- subset(dat, language == "FR")[,-21] # Remove language identifier column
      
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", "Sujet", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year","Année(s) de recensement couverte(s) par l’item", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units","Unités géographiques", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage","Couverture géographique", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format","Format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    }
    
    
    if(!is.null(input$subject)) {
      filtered_dat <- filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "), function(x) any(input$subject %in% x)),]
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    }
    
    if(!is.null(input$census_year)) {
      filtered_dat <- filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "), function(x) any(input$census_year %in% x)),]
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    }
    
    if(!is.null(input$geo_units)){
      filtered_dat <- filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "), function(x) any(input$geo_units %in% x)),]
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    }
    
    if(!is.null(input$geo_coverage)){
      filtered_dat<-filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "), function(x) any(input$geo_coverage %in% x)), ]
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "format", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "))))), selected = input$format)
    }
    
    if(!is.null(input$format)){
      filtered_dat<-filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$format, ", "), function(x) any(input$format %in% x)), ]
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "census_year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$yearItem, ", "))))), selected = input$census_year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoUnits, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_coverage", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$geoCov, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_coverage)
    }
    
    #Table output
    output$ex1 <- DT::renderDT({
      if (input$language == TRUE) {
        
        hide_columns <- c("printVol", "Language", "pageNum", "productID","contentType",
                          "altTitle","author",  "releaseDate", "relatedMat","quality",  "notes", "addNotes")
        visible_colnames <- c("Title", "Link", "Census year (of publication)",
                              "Census Year(s) covered by item", "Subject",
                              "Geographic coverage", "Geographic units","Format")
        
        DT::datatable(filtered_dat, 
                      colnames = visible_colnames,  # Use the names of visible columns
                      rownames = FALSE,
                      selection = "single", # only allows single selection
                      options = list(language = list(url = '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/English.json'), 
                                     columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE,  targets=hide_columns))),
                      escape = FALSE)
        
      } else {
        hide_columns <- c("printVol", "Language", "pageNum", "productID","contentType",
                          "altTitle","author",  "releaseDate", "relatedMat","quality",  "notes", "addNotes")
        visible_colnames <- c("Titre", "Link", "Année de recensement (de la publication)",
                              "Année(s) de recensement couverte(s) par l’item", "Sujet",
                              "Couverture géographique", "Unités géographiques","Format")
        DT::datatable(filtered_dat, 
                      colnames = visible_colnames,  # Use the names of visible columns
                      rownames = FALSE,
                      selection = "single", # only allows single selection
                      options = list(language = list(url = '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/French.json'), 
                                     columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE,  targets=hide_columns))),
                      escape = FALSE)
      }
    })
    
    
    # Details tab output
    output$details <- DT::renderDT({
      req(input$ex1_rows_selected)
      
      selectedRows <- input$ex1_rows_selected
      if (length(selectedRows) > 0) {
        selectedData <- filtered_dat[selectedRows, ]
        
        # Rename the columns
        if (input$language == TRUE) {
          column_names <- c(
            "Title", "Link", "Census year (of publication)",
            "Census Year(s) covered by item", "Subject",
            "Geographic coverage", "Geographic units","Format",
            "Found in (print volume)", "Language", "Page number", "Product ID",
            "Content Type", "Parallel Title", "Author/Producer", "Release Date",
            "Related Materials", "Quality", "Notes", "Additional Notes")
          
        } else {
          column_names <- c("Titre", "Link", "Année de recensement (de la publication)",
                            "Année(s) de recensement couverte(s) par l’item", "Sujet",
                            "Couverture géographique", "Unités géographiques","Format",
                            "Trouvé dans (document papier original seulement)", "Language", "Numéros de pages", "Identifiant du produit",
                            "Type de contenu", "Titre parallèle", "Auteur / producteur du contenu", "Date de parution",
                            "Matériels et documentation reliés", "Qualité de la numérisation ou des données", "Notes d'accès aux données", "Notes complémentaires")
        }
        
        colnames(selectedData) <- column_names
        
        # Create a transposed data frame
        transposedData <- data.frame(
          Category = rep(column_names, each = nrow(selectedData)),
          Value = as.vector(t(selectedData))
        )
        
        if (input$language == TRUE) {
          # Modify the presentation of column names
          col_names_html <- sprintf('<div style="font-size: 12px;">%s</div>', colnames(transposedData))
          
          datatable <- DT::datatable(transposedData,
                                     rownames = FALSE,
                                     selection = "single", # only allows single selection
                                     options = list(
                                       language = list(url = '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/English.json'),
                                       paging = FALSE,  # Disable pagination
                                       lengthMenu = list(c(-1), c("All")),  # Show all entries
                                       columnDefs = list(
                                         list(width = 'auto', targets = 0:1)  # Set column width to "auto" for the first two columns
                                       ),
                                       dom = 't'  # Show only the table
                                     ),
                                     escape = FALSE)  # Set escape to FALSE to allow HTML rendering
          
          datatable %>% 
            DT::formatStyle(
              columns = 'Category',  # Apply formatting to the 'Category' column
              fontWeight = 'bold'  # Set the font weight to bold
            )
          
        } else {
          # Modify the presentation of column names
          col_names_html <- sprintf('<div style="font-size: 12px;">%s</div>', colnames(transposedData))
          
          datatable <- DT::datatable(transposedData,
                                     rownames = FALSE,
                                     selection = "single", # only allows single selection
                                     options = list(
                                       language = list(url = '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/French.json'),
                                       paging = FALSE,  # Disable pagination
                                       lengthMenu = list(c(-1), c("All")),  # Show all entries
                                       columnDefs = list(
                                         list(width = 'auto', targets = 0:1)  # Set column width to "auto" for the first two columns
                                       ),
                                       dom = 't'  # Show only the table
                                     ),
                                     escape = FALSE)  # Set escape to FALSE to allow HTML rendering
          
          datatable %>% 
            DT::formatStyle(
              columns = 'Category',  # Apply formatting to the 'Category' column
              fontWeight = 'bold'  # Set the font weight to bold
            )
          
        }
      }
    })
    
    
    
    
  })
  
})



#Enable bookmarking to generate URL

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

This may not be the best way to set up the code and I still consider myself a beginner in R and R Shiny. Any help on this issue or just condensing things in general would be most appreciated. In addition, I can provide some sample data if need be.

Thank you in advance!